# Editing a large text file with awk or any other editor: loop for changing a n-th line

Tags: awk, notepad++, notepad

I have a large (2Gb) text file, with the following structure:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
176 (comment: line 1)
  i =        1 (comment: line 2)
H -0.073307  8.187645  4.065238 (comment: line 3)
H 1.964613  5.187168  7.038084 (comment: line 4)
... (comment: lines 5 - 178)
176 (comment: line 179)
  i =        2 (comment: line 180)
H -0.055549  8.224715  4.041477 (comment: line 181)
H 1.971048  5.193901  7.012246 (comment: line 182)
... (comment: lines 183 - 356)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is an output from a Molecular Dynamics run.

176 is the number of atoms, 'i =        n' is the number of iteration,  and the lines below are the atomic coordinates.  I need to write a script to modify the two first lines for each iteration in the following way very large txt in the following way:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
176 (comment: line 1)
  i =        1, time =        0.500, E =      -100.0000000000 (comment: line 2)  
H -0.073307  8.187645  4.065238 (comment: line 3)
H 1.964613  5.187168  7.038084 (comment: line 4)
... (comment: lines 5 - 178)
176 (comment: line 179)
  i =        2, time =        1.000, E =      -100.0000000000 (comment: line 2)
H -0.055549  8.224715  4.041477 (comment: line 181)
H 1.971048  5.193901  7.012246 (comment: line 182)
(comment: lines 183 - 356)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It means that for iteration i = n, there is a time = 0.500 * n, and the Energy (need to put a constant here, -100.0000000000), so eg.

```
i =        1000, time =        500.000, E =      -100.0000000000
```

I know it's trivial, but I am completely lost.

Comment: are the empty lines part of the output?

Comment: After you pasted the code/content, you can select it, and click the `{}` button or use keyboard shortkey `Ctrl+K` to format it.  And please tell us what you have tried, it's important to show your own effort to get good answers.

Comment: No empty lines in the output, sorry I have never used stack overflow...

Comment: Are the `----` lines really present in your input file? If not then remove them from your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^[[:space:]]+i =[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/) {
    $0 = sprintf("%s, time =        %0.3f, E =        -100.0000000000%s", substr($0,1,RLENGTH), 0.5 * (++n), substr($0,RLENGTH+1))
} 1' file
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
176 (comment: line 1)
  i =        1, time =        0.500, E =        -100.0000000000 (comment: line 2)
H -0.073307  8.187645  4.065238 (comment: line 3)
H 1.964613  5.187168  7.038084 (comment: line 4)
... (comment: lines 5 - 178)
176 (comment: line 179)
  i =        2, time =        1.000, E =        -100.0000000000 (comment: line 180)
H -0.055549  8.224715  4.041477 (comment: line 181)
H 1.971048  5.193901  7.012246 (comment: line 182)
... (comment: lines 183 - 356)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```